# Moment no parsea a utc correctamente

Tags: nodejs, mongoose, momentjs

Tengo data en una base de datos que se encuentra en UTC 0, para consultar por un formulario se envia un rango de fechas desde el frontend. El frontend toma por defecto la fecha y hora actual.

En mi país la sona horaria es UTC -4 por lo que estoy parseando las fechas a UTC 0 con el metodo utc de moment, Pero me doy cuenta que no hace ningun efecto.

Para probarlo le envio las fechas 12/05/2022 12:00 PM to 12/05/2022 12:10 PM y le aplico moment.utc().toIsoString(), pero el resultado es el mismo.

aqui un log de lo que me devuelve:

```
: fecha de inicio 2022-12-05T12:10:35
: fecha de fin 2022-12-05T13:13:35
: fecha de inicio parsed 2022-12-05T12:10:35.000Z
: fecha de fin parsed 2022-12-05T13:13:35.000Z
```

Y este es una muestra de mi codigo:

```
exports.getHistoriesDetailed = async (req, res = response) => {

const userId = req.body.user_id;
const dateStart = req.body.date_from;
const dateEnd = req.body.date_to;

console.log( 'fecha de inicio', dateStart )
console.log( 'fecha de fin', dateEnd )

console.log( 'fecha de inicio parsed', moment(dateStart).utc().toISOString()) 
console.log( 'fecha de fin parsed', moment(dateEnd).utc().toISOString()) 

const query = { 
    userID: parseInt(userID),
    date_created: {
        $gte : new Date(moment(dateStart).toISOString()),
        $lt : new Date(moment(dateEnd).toISOString())
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cris223511.dev ya lo he hecho y es el mismo resultado

Comment: Lo que veo es que solo esta pasando en mi servidor de producción, localmente en mi maquina funciona. En mi servidor de producción la zona horaria es UTC 0

Comment: Creo que deberías es usar `moment.utc(startDate)` en vez de `moment(startDate).utc()`